# Difference between EventLog.WriteEntry and EventLog.WriteEvent methods

Tags: .net, .net-2.0

I tried using `WriteEntry` and `WriteEvent` methods of `EventLog` class.

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("Saravanan", "Application logs an entry", 
                     EventLogEntryType.Information, 2, 3);
EventLog.WriteEvent("Saravanan",  new EventInstance(2, 3), 
                                 "Application logs an event");
```

Both output the same result.

Is there any difference in usage of these methods?

If there are only minor difference, why was it not done through a overload of either `WriteEvent()` or `WriteEntry()` methods, instead of introducing a new method?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`EventLog.WriteEntry` is a "quick and dirty" way to write to the event log where you can write a string. `EventLog.WriteEvent` enables you to take full advantage of the native Win32 API. However, to do that you are supposed to create a localized message file you then compile using the [message compiler (mc.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385638(VS.85).aspx). Each event can contain substitution strings and can be localized to match the locale on the computer.

To avoid this extra step of creating a message file the .Net wrapper for the event log API use messages that simply inserts the strings supplied as arguments. These message are used by `EventLog.WriteEntry` and are stored as embedded resources in `EventLogMessages.dll` in the .Net folder.

Normally using `EventLog.WriteEntry` is adequate, but if you need to localize your messages or want to maintain them outside your source code you should create a message file and use `EventLog.WriteEvent`.